# Wordpress Subdomain MultiSite on localhost XAMPP on :8080 with IIS taking port 80

Tags: multisite, apache, localhost, iis, xampp

I currently have Windows 7 , 64 bit on which I am running an IIS on localhost:80 and I installed XAMPP on localhost:8080. I have 15 individual wordpress sites but now i need a subdomain multisite wordpress.

I created wp.dev:8080 in the hosts file for multisite, and correctly amended the apache virtual file. All worked until I added the `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` to the config file. When I clicked on the new Network menu option in wordpress, I got an error:

> ERROR: You cannot install a network of sites with your server address.
>        You cannot use port numbers such as :8080.

Now here is the problem. localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1 on port 80 for IIS. And Apache is taking all of localhost:8080. can I somehow split the localhost:80 traffic by assigning wp.dev to be the only :80 to go to Apache and the remainder to continue going to IIS. How would I define that since in Apache I already have *:8080 defined? Please help, my files are below:

> Hosts file on c/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
>   this is root of iis if i dont specify port (:80) and if i specify port (:8080) go to xampp
>   127.0.0.1 localhost
>   these below are the :8080 individual wordpress on xampp 
>   127.0.0.1 sb.localhost tw.localhost ups.localhost vet.localhost box.localhost ea.localhost
>   multisite below
>   127.0.0.1 wp.dev

**This is my Apache config file in D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

> NameVirtualHost *:8080
>
> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
>   ServerName localhost

**This is a working wordpress normal blog**

> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/ki/abce/wordpress"
>   ServerName abce.localhost
>   
>   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all

**This below is how network subdomain blog that would work if not for 8080 problem**

> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/alllive/wordpress"
>   ServerAlias *.wp.dev
>   ServerName wp.dev
>   
>   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: I run IIS and Apache and I do the opposite, I ran Apache on `localhost:80` and IIS on `:8080`. You might need to change your windows host file, I think this is a know issue.

Comment: @Wyck, Thanks. I am trying to do just that now.. huge headache and waste of time... You should post the answer, I will wait and give you points in a day or two if nothing better comes along, cuz i searched for hours, and nothing.

Comment: I think you'd have a much better chance of an answer on ServerFault - requesting a move :)

Comment: Just for starters ... Setup of WordPress multisite as localhost needs to be sub-directory install. And you will need to move to port 80 for Apache.  This might help you ... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-3-network-multisite-on-a-local-development-site    and @AndreaR or Ipstenu on the Multsite Forum are brilliant

Comment: maybe your help is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378515/xampp-when-configured-to-port-8080-and-hosts-file-and-wordpress-mu-install-iss)

Comment: @Damien Wordpress multisite localhost does NOT need to me sub-directory, and I've set up plenty subdomains on localhost. Please don't confuse people if you've never done it, there only 100 tutorials on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I gave up and moved to port 80, though i think what @Boultge suggest (the link) would have probably done it, but I read it too late.

Here are the files tho that are letting me run XAMPP WordPress MU sub-domain Multisite on localhost as wp.dev with 20 additional WordPress individual sites. I shortened it because i have 8 sites per line and both my wpmu and regular wordpress sites all look the same, i just have to be careful not to pick a name for a new multisite domain that i am already using for the regular wordpress

Here is the `c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1 wp.dev
>
> 127.0.0.1 somename.wp.dev someothername.wp.dev wpmu1.wp.dev wpmu2.wp.dev wpmu3.wp.dev

In `httpd.conf` file located in `xampp/apache/conf` I have (all else left as is):

> Listen 80                 # line 47
>
> ServerName localhost:80   # line
>   184

In `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `xampp/apache/conf/extra`:

> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs" ServerName localhost
>
> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/regular-wordpress-1/wordpress" ServerName
>
> somename.wp.dev
>
> "D:/xampp/htdocs/regular-wordpress-1/wordpress"> Options Indexes
>
> FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes Order allow,deny Allow from all
>
> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/regular-wordpress-2/wordpress"
>
> ServerName someothername.wp.dev
>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
>
> Order allow,deny
>
> Allow from all

The rest of them above are all the same, each one a completely independent wordpress install.
At the very end of `httpd-vhosts.conf` comes multisite domains below:

> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/wpmu-home/wordpress"
>
> ServerAlias wpmu1.wp.dev
>
> ServerAlias wpmu2.wp.dev
>
> ServerAlias wpmu3.wp.dev
>
> ServerName wp.dev
>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
>
> Order allow,deny
>
> Allow from all

No other directive is activated besides what's here in the httpd-vhosts. With this sub domain wordpress multisite on xampp works fine though on port 80.